# Odoo 11 - update modules using windows cmd

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have recently installed my custom CSS module and added a javascript file that broke odoo and now I can only see my logo and top bar.

web.assets_backend.js:2632 Could not get content for /mymocule/static/src/js/mymodule-main.js defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'.

How can I update / delete or uninstall this module using windows server.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you have access to the database?

Comment: What you can do is going back to a working version of your module (if you don't know, remove the most code you can). Then update this module using the options `-d <your_database_name> -u <module_name>` while starting Odoo.